# How can bixby read text that is not displayed?

Tags: bixby

I would like to have a bixby result-view read text that is different from what is displayed.

I see that I can create a dialog and match it to the results, or I can also put it in the message field of a result-view. Both of these options let you specify a "template", which has a [speech key option](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/reference/type/template), but I have not been able to get that to work to see what the speech key actually does. It might be what I am looking for but I cannot find any examples of the syntax and usually it complains about missing values.

Is this possible to have different displayed vs spoken text? Even if this functionality is not what the speech key is for, can you guys explain and give me an example of what the usage of the speech key would look like just so i can understand going forward?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is this possible to have different displayed vs spoken text?

Yes, that is exactly what the speech key option is for. What trouble are you running into for it?

Here's a sample use case.

```
  content {
    template ("This is the displayed text.") {
      speech ("This is the text that Bixby will read.")
    }
  }
```

> I see that I can create a dialog and match it to the results, or I can also put it in the message field of a result-view.

Both ways are legitimate, but note that is it significantly harder to override the dialog generated in the `message` field for `result-view`.

Instead, if you use normal `dialog` files (such as `dialog (Result)`), you can write different [match patterns](https://bixbydevelopers.com/dev/docs/sample-capsules/samples/matching-pattern) to create different dialog for different situations.

Comment: I could not get the syntax correct and could not find any examples of using an optional key with a mandatory value. Thank you so much!!!